# How to make PhpStorm reflect TypeScript tsconfig.json in .vue files?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, phpstorm, vuejs2, webstorm

I'm using Vue.js (webpack + vueify) and TypeScript. ts configuration seems to be working but only with `.ts` files.

For example in `tsconfig.json` I have

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": false,
```

So `strictNullChecks` works fine in `.ts` files:

[image]

But not in `.vue`:

[image]

Error:

> Initializer type null is not assignable to variable type string

TypeScript doesn't throw compile errors, only PhpStorm seems to have problems with detecting configuration.

What do I have to do so my configuration in `tsconfig.json` reflects in `.vue` files as well?

Comment: I would suggest posting the same question at WebStorm forum: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367229-WebStorm

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521143/how-to-make-intellij-idea-lint-ts-script-in-vue

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm own parser doesn't use your `tsconfig.json` for errors reporting. Setting **"strictNullChecks": false** only affects the TypeScript service that is used for error highlighting `.ts` files by default (if **Use TypeScript Service** is enabled in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript`)

But Typescript compiler/service doesn't currently handle `.vue` files (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10427), so it's only enabled for `.ts` files; for typescript in `.vue` files, WebStorm own parser is used instead

Another problem is that WebStorm behaves differently in embedded typescript - it accepts assigning null in `.ts` files, but not in `.vue` files (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28029)